# How to share a hyperlink to a parametrized view in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-v4

I created a web-app that uses reactjs. Now the basics of the app are :-

1. Create Topics/Sub topics.
2. Display them (this uses react )

Now 2nd task is explained as :-

1. Show all the topics/sub topics list.
2. Clicking any of them sends json req and the data is recieved and displayed.

Now I want to share the topic with link , however on clicking any of the topic only one elemnt of the html renders and the url remains the same.

So this is what i want to do -

1. On clicking , send json req and recieve data ( done )
2. Change the url ( I want to know if it is possible using the same react page? )

Comment: I think you can. You only need to make the Route or Link to link to the topics or subtopics with a params. For example <Route path="topic/:topicId" component={Topic} />. In your Topic component, you get the param topicId and use this id to fetch the data from your api using axios, fetch or request... You can do it in your componentDidMount

Comment: Is there any other way ?  ... instead of showing new component i want to change the state of the existing component .... is that possible ?

Comment: @PulkitJoshi perhaps showing some relevant parts of your code could help here, but I am also new to reactjs.

Comment: There is no error in the code to search for :) . I am just trying to find a way to do what I stated in the question. I want to set the state of the component depending upon the url or set url depending upon the componenet state